# реверс-инжеринг

Tags: c++, c

Есть-ли то, от чего отталкиваться в любом случае?
Не могу понять, как правильно нужно действовать, не могу найти нужный материал.

Знаю, что многие с легкостью реверсят многие источники.
Многим также интересно, как это делается. Многие рассказывают, как это делается - но очень много воды!

Нужно четкое понятие: с чего начать, что взять, что нужно знать - желательно пояснить весь алгоритм.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно: знать ассемблер (или p-code) целевой платформы, IDA Pro, отладчик под целевую платформу. А потом опыт нарабатывать, алгоритмов теоретических под любые случаи не бывает.

Comment: Мне нужно получить из скомпилированной dll - ассемблер?, а потом воспользоваться дизассемблером? или читать и переписывать под ассемблер? А потом как обратно в dll? А еще бы знать, как получить ассемблер или это и есть dll?

Comment: Еще раз: знать ассемблер (или p-code) целевой платформы, IDA Pro. Начните с этих двух пунктов.

Comment: Стоп. dll компилируется в машинный код, так? А машинный код это ассемблер или что, не понял. IDA Pro нужно купить, чтобы норм работало, так ведь? - В машинном коде явно указывают, что это язык ассемблера, как быть не понимаю - то есть открыть через текстовой редактор dll и это и есть ассемблер или я не правильно понял? Что - то неувязочки, какие-то. Есть более правильный ответ?

Comment: ЕЩЕ РАЗ: изучайте ассемблер под указанную платформу. Изучайте IDA Pro. Вы не начали ни того, ни другого судя по вопросам.